# Complex Content Type, modules?

Tags: views, 7, nodes

I've been trying to figure out how to create a content type "a course" that has title, description, duration, instrucor details and contains video lessons.
I made three different content types - courses, videos and instructors but couldn't figure it out how to relate it. I've been trying with View but if someone could suggest module/tips how-to would be much appreciated.

BR, Ivan Ivanov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:

To your course content type add new field of entity ref type and refer videos content type.
Add second field to your course ct and refer instructions content type.

When you create new course you will be able to select instructions and videos

[Tutorial (simple)](http://drupal.org/node/1327954)

[Youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcVz8Thxq48)

Comment: Thank u for the promt response. Tried with Entity Reference but these two fields that I had added in the course content type refer to the title of the videos and instructors only not to the whole content, meaning each video has title, thumbnail, descrition, duration etc and each instructor name, experience, age etc....Wanna get all this info in one. Is it possible?

Comment: just to add - see this capture for reference http://s22.postimg.org/vt9c9gwi9/Capture.png

Comment: The entity reference is just a "tunnel" to your different content-types. With views-module e.g. you can strip out the needed fields of a referenced entity.

Comment: Managed to do it exactly with Entity Ref Module. Thank you very much mate :)